# PHP: Mysql Query returns no value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Trying to do some simple PHP coding to start on my project. I am trying to get database info by the url entered, but when i type the valid test url, it returns nothing. It outputs as:

ID: DISCUSSION NAME:

And right next to those, they should have the value from the database. But they don't. So can anyone help me?

```
$getdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discussions WHERE urlname ='" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "'") or die(mysql_error());
 while ($info = mysql_fetch_array( $getdata ));
{
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>ID: </th> <td>".$info['id'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>DISCUSSION NAME:</th> <td>".$info['discussion'] . "</td> "; 
}
```

MY DATABASE INFO:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b89I8.png

[image]

Comment: Does `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` have a trailing slash?  Also, this is a huge security hole :) Try using mysql_real_escape_string() around your server call

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that, this is just a test script so no worries :) and yes, it does have a trailing slash

Comment: Well there's your problem!  The `urlname` field is just `/test1` instead of `/test1/`.  Try editing it to that and see if it works.

Either that or `...WHERE urlname ='" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "/...'`

Comment: what does var_dump($info); in the whole loop show ?

Comment: Just wanted to say it's nice of you actually post the database info and the code. It makes it easier for people to quickly spot the problem.

Comment: Tried both, and so far no luck :/ just a blank output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code has a bad semi colon

```
$getdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discussions WHERE urlname ='" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "'") or die(mysql_error());
 while ($info = mysql_fetch_array( $getdata ));
{
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>ID: </th> <td>".$info['id'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>DISCUSSION NAME:</th> <td>".$info['discussion'] . "</td> "; 
}
```

this line

```
 while ($info = mysql_fetch_array( $getdata ));
```

should be

```
 while ($info = mysql_fetch_array( $getdata ))
```

Comment: Well I'll be damned.  Nice!

Comment: Everyone overlooks the obvious parts.. chuckle.

Comment: Good time to mention that you should look into mysqli_* functions instead of the mysql_* ones that you are using which are deprecated. Also you are vulnerable to injection because you are not sanitizing the input.